# FluentValidation for interdependent properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

Lets say I have a start number and an end number. End number must be greater then start number. What is the best way to check end number compared to start number?
Here is what I have. I'm using `Must()` method. Is there a better way?

```
RuleFor(e => e.StartNumber)
    .NotNull()
    .InclusiveBetween(ID_MIN, ID_MAX);

RuleFor(e => e.EndNumber)
    .NotNull()
    .InclusiveBetween(ID_MIN, ID_MAX)
    .Must((mid, endNumber) => endNumber > mid.StartNumber);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are validating that the `EndNumber` is greater than the `StartNumber` you might consider using the overload of the built-in [`GreaterThan`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#greater-than-validator) validator that accepts a lambda expression in order to reference the `StartNumber`.

Doing so, you benefit from having the built-in validation message available.

```
RuleFor(e => e.EndNumber)
    .NotNull()
    .InclusiveBetween(ID_MIN, ID_MAX)
    .GreaterThan(o => o.StartNumber);
```

---

But in the end, there's nothing wrong with your current approach.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that several of the built in rules methods have overloads that take an expression. I think its a better option to using Must() in this case.